# How to create a default user in global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The project I'm working on uses ms identity hooked into a mongo database. For deployment purposes (since there is no public registration), I'd like for the page to automatically check for an admin account and create one if its missing. I can't seem to do that however since there is no owin context when executing Application_Start() and thats the only way i know how to get to the user manager outside the whole mvc thing. Right now, It checks for the admin account every time the home page is loaded but it occurred to me that this is unnecessary bloat and I'd like to move it to somewhere thats visited less frequently.

Comment: You could do a direct query on the database to see if there's a user. You don't necessarily need UserManager for that.

Comment: I need it to create the user though, otherwise I don't know how I'd get the security stamp

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can provide you here is create an install.aspx. This you will execute manually and create a user for you.

In addition you could perform various application tasks, such as, refreshing application variables and so on...